# C++ inheritance and virtual funcions

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, virtual

Here is my task:

Design classes Circle and Square which are inherited from class Shape (which contains center of gravity which is common characteristic for all shapes, function for moving center of gravity for specific value and virtual functions circumference, area and read). Classes should have specific functions for calculating circumference and area, as well as for reading data members.

Here is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    float x;
    float y;
public:
    Point();
    Point(float,float);
    ~Point();
};

Point::Point() {
}

Point::Point(float a,float b) {
    x=a;
    y=b;
}

Point::~Point() {
}

class Shape {
public:
    Shape(void);
    Shape(Point);
    virtual float circumference(void) {}
    virtual float area(void) {}
protected:
    Point center_of_gravity;
};

Shape::Shape(void) {
}

Shape::Shape(Point a) {
    center_of_gravity=a;
}

//----------------------------------------

class Circle:public Shape {
private:
    float radius;
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    Circle();
    Circle(float);
    virtual float circumference(void);
    virtual float area(void);
};

Circle::Circle(void) {
}

Circle::Circle(float a) {
    radius=a;
}

float Circle::area(void) {
    float area_of_circle;
    const float pi=3.14159;
    area_of_circle=radius*radius*pi;
    return area_of_circle;
}

float Circle::circumference(void) {
    float circumference_of_circle;
    const float pi=3.14159;
    circumference_of_circle=2*radius*pi;
    return circumference_of_circle;
}

//----------------------------------------

class Square:public Shape {
private:
    float length;
public:
    Square();
    Square(float);
    virtual float circumference(void);
    virtual float area(void);
};

Square::Square(void) {
}

Square::Square(float a) {
    length=a;
}

float Square::area(void) {
    float area_of_circle;
    area_of_circle=length*length;
    return area_of_circle;
}

float Square::circumference(void) {
    float circumference_of_square;
    circumference_of_square=4*length;
    return circumference_of_square;
}

int main() {
    float a,b;
    cout<<"Enter coordinates of center of gravity: "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    Point center_of_grav(a,b);
    cout<<"Enter length of square: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    Square square(a);
    cout<<"Enter radius of circle: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    Circle circle(a);
    Shape *shape1=&circle;
    Shape *shape2=&square;
    cout<<"Area of circle is "<<shape1->area()<<", circumference is "<<shape1->circumference()<<endl;
    cout<<"Area of square is "<<shape2->area()<<", circumference is "<<shape2->circumference()<<endl;
}
```

Is it ok? How can I realize function for moving center of gravity? 
How can I read center of gravity for Circle and Square (it is inherited from class Shape)? They mean it (I think) when they say "...as well as for reading data members."

EDIT:

After I put all suggestion I got in one place:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Point{
    private:
    float x;
    float y;
    public:
    Point();
    Point(float,float);
    ~Point();
    friend class Shape;
    };

    Point::Point(){
    }

    Point::Point(float a,float b){
    x=a;
    y=b;
    }

    Point::~Point(){
    }

    //----------------------------------------

    class Shape{
    public:
    Shape(void);
    Shape(Point);
    virtual float area(void)=0;
    virtual float circumference(void)=0;
    protected:
    float x_coordinate;
    float y_coordinate;
    Point center_of_gravity;
    };

    Shape::Shape(void){
    }

    Shape::Shape(Point a){
    center_of_gravity=a;
    x_coordinate=a.x;
    y_coordinate=a.y;
    }

    //----------------------------------------

    class Circle:public Shape{
    private:
    float radius;
    public:
    Circle();
    Circle(Point,float);
    virtual float area(void);
    virtual float circumference(void);
    };

    Circle::Circle(void){
    radius=0;
    }

    Circle::Circle(Point p,float a) : Shape(p), radius(a){
    }

    float Circle::area(void){
    float area_of_circle;
    const float pi=3.14159;
    area_of_circle=radius*radius*pi;
    return area_of_circle;
    }

    float Circle::circumference(void){
    float circumference_of_circle;
    const float pi=3.14159;
    circumference_of_circle=2*radius*pi;
    return circumference_of_circle;
    }

    //----------------------------------------

    class Square:public Shape{
    private:
    float length;
    public:
    Square();
    Square(Point,float);
    virtual float area(void);
    virtual float circumference(void);
    };

    Square::Square(void){
    length=0;
    }

    Square::Square(Point p,float a) : Shape(p), length(a){
    }


    float Square::area(void){
    float area_of_circle;
    area_of_circle=length*length;
    return area_of_circle;
    }

    float Square::circumference(void){
    float circumference_of_square;
    circumference_of_square=4*length;
    return circumference_of_square;
    }

    //----------------------------------------

    int main(){
    float a,b;
    cout<<"Enter coordinates of center of gravity: "<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    Point center_of_grav(a,b);
    cout<<"Enter length of square: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    Square square(center_of_grav,a);
    cout<<"Enter radius of circle: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    Circle circle(center_of_grav,a);
    Shape *shape1=&circle;
    Shape *shape2=&square;
    cout<<"Area of circle is "<<shape1->area()<<", circumference is "<<shape1->circumference()<<endl;
    cout<<"Area of square is "<<shape2->area()<<", circumference is "<<shape2->circumference()<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: I would declare `circumference()` and `area()` as pure method in the `Shape` class. (`virtual float area() = 0;`).

Comment: Squares do not have a circumference

Comment: Simply access the `protected` (visible to subclasses) member variable `center_of_gravity` in member functions of `Circle` and `Square`.

Comment: To start with, learn how to call the parent constructor from a child class (and in the process about *constructor initializer lists* in general), then modify your `Square` and `Circle` constructors to take a point as extra argument.

Comment: @jhnnslschnr, but center_of_gravity is not "normal" type of variable, it is of type "Point", it is characterized with two floats. How can I access floats of center_of_gravity variable?

Comment: Side note regarding @EdHeal's comment: 'perimeter' is the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1.Constructor design

How will you set their gravity center ?

```
Point center_of_grav(a,b);
...
Square square(c);   // what's the gravity center ?
```

You have to design the constructor of the derived, so that it has all information required to construct the base:

```
Square square(center_of_grav, c);
```

To achieve this, you have to define it in the following way (of course adapt the class definition accordingly):

```
Square::Square(Point p, float a) : Shape(p), lentgh(a) {
    // ... reserve this for more complex initisalisations
}
```

*Note that your default constructor leave the objects uninitialized.*

## 2.Design of Shape

**Very important:** Shape is a polymorphic class with virtual functions.  You shall take the habit to define a virtual destructor in this case.

**Minor remark:** It makes no sense to create directely a Shape object.  It's an abstract concept.  There is no default rule to calculate an area or a circumference that could apply to most of the shape.  Therefore, I'd strongly suggest to define these two functions as pure virtual:

```
class Shape {
    ...
    virtual float circumference(void) =0;  // pure virtual
    virtual float area(void) = 0; 
    ...
};
```

Advantage:  as soon as you have a pure virtual function in a class, this class becomes abstract, and you won't be able to instantiate an object of that class by error.  The compiler will make sure that you instatiate only concrete derivates of the abstract concept.

## 3.Make sure your code complies with requirements

Well it's a detail and you certainly have taken care of it, but:

> Classes should have specific functions for calculating circumference
>   and area, **as well as for reading data members**.

So I think you should foresee some getters to access to the protected data:

Example:

```
class Shape {
    ...
    Point get_gravity_center();  
    ...
};

Point Shape::get_gravity_center() {
    return center_of_gravity;
}
```

I let you complete the others.  Simply imagine that you have to print in `main()` the description of a circle (coordinates of the center and radius), and you'll see the getters that are missing.

**Edit following your question:**

As you we've defined the getter for the center of gravity at the shape level, you don't need to define it again in the derivates.  You could then simply call it in main().   The problem is that you also need to access to the coordinats of that point.  So:

```
class Point {
    ... 
    float get_x() { return x; }
    float get_y() { return y; }
    ...
};
```

With this you can write in main():

```
cout << "Circle of center ("<<circle.get_gravity_center().get_x()<<","
                            << circle.get_gravity_center().get_y()<<")"<<endl;
```

*P.S:  with the center_of_gravity as member of shape, you no longer need to duplicate the coordinates otf that point.*

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for your reply. Pleas look at my first post, I put new code there. However, I'm still unsure about function which return center_of_gravity variable. What should I modify in new code in order, for example, to print center_of_gravity for circle and square I declared in main program (user will input there also x and y coordinates as you can see) ?

Comment: @etf Hi, I've edited, trying to answer your additional question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question: Is it necessary to realize Square constructor in one line? Square::Square(Point p, float a) : Shape(p), lentgh(a) {
    // ... reserve this for more complex initisalisations
}

Comment: For the base constructor you're obliged to do so. For the memers you have the choice of either constructing them "on the line" or having them default constructed and initialize them in the body of the constructor

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it is not OK.  Your code does show some pretty clear thinking, so that's good.  It just needs to be finished.  All data members of all classes must be given values when objects are constructed.  Otherwise, they get random values, and that is never good practice.  So init the CG in the Shape constructor.

Also, remove x and y from circle, if you mean them to represent CG -- that info is inherited already.

Finally, to realize a function for moving CG, I'd recommend adding a setter method to the Shape class, where it can be inherited by those other two classes.  With that, you should be good to go.